# Why is there a difference in notation between vectors?

Tags: notation, vectors, tensors

For example, I know that a vector is represented by $a^iv_i$, where $a^i$ is a component, and $v_i$ is a covariant basis vector. A dual vector can be represented by $a_iv^i$, where $a_i$ is a component and $v^i$ is a contravariant basis vector; but what is represented by ${a_i}{v_i}$? Is that just a misuse of notation that early calculus classes use?

Comment: I've edited for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. For what it's worth I think this third notation can't be applied in this context, in other words, it doesn't mean anything. On the other hand, when not in the framework of tensor calculus, this can just mean a scalar product of two vectors with summation implied by repeated index. It depends on where you saw this notation

Comment: I saw this notation (that I'm questioning) in early multivariable calculus and linear algebra classes.

Comment: Do you see this notation ($a_iv_i$) when you deal with inner product of two vectors or something?

Comment: Yes, inner products or sums/differences @edm.

Comment: One more detail I want to know. Did you see all three notations used by the same teacher? Or are the notations used by different teachers?

Comment: Different teachers and different independent study materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really a misuse of notation.  When working with linear(!) $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is no real need to distinguish between contravariant and covariant (since they transform in the same way with respect to an orthogonal linear change of coordinates).  The need to distinguish upstairs and downstairs indices came with general transformation of coordinates and whether you contract with the denominator or the numerator of the Jacobian $\dfrac{\partial (x')}{\partial (x)}$, which isn't relevant or visible in calculus classes.

Comment: I thought it might be this. I just wanted to confirm. Thank you.

Comment: Also one reason not to introduce the upstairs indices in e.g. linear algebra is that it merely confuses students, e.g., the vandermonde matrix would be very confusing if you distinguish upstairs and downstairs for the matrix suffices, especially when you start to manipulate it to prove its determinant.

Comment: This is not ok. We use general transformation of coordinates even in $\Bbb R^n$. Not to mention, even when we only pay our attention to linear transformation of coordinates, and only to tensors on a vector space instead of tensor field (before we do tensor calculus), we can see the difference between upper index and lower index.

Comment: @edm that's why I restrict to orthogonal linear transformations, which don't see the upper/lower distinction.

Comment: @edm do you agree with the most recent comment?

Answer (score 1):

This notation is known as Einstein's summation notation. I must say, I would be surprised if you see this in early calculus class. It is only after we have seen many times in tensor calculus that the summation dummy index $i$ only appears exactly twice, once in upper index, once in lower index, that we decide to drop the summation sign $\sum_i$. Forcing early calculus students to accept the notation does not simplify anything.

To the topic, when you try to take inner product of two vectors $x^ie_i$ and $y^ie_i$, some people may mistakenly write the inner product as $x^iy^i$. But Einstein summation notation makes it explicit that summation only occurs when the index $i$ appears once in the superscript, and once in the subscript. This one $x^iy^i$ is not ok.

The correct way to write the inner product of two vectors in Einstein summation notation is rather $x^i\delta_{ij}y^j$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, representing the canonical inner product.

Comment: You see that at a very first university course, e.g. [First year Algebra and Geometry course (University of Cambridge)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk//user/sjc1/teaching/AandG/notes.pdf) page 30-31.